# Elliptical path followed by a charged particle

Tags: forces, charge, centripetal-force

I was solving some problems in which a charge **Q(+ve)** was kept fixed and another charge **q(-ve)** was given a velocity at an angle say $\theta$ with the line joining the two particles. Distance between the particles being **d**

[image]

Each time i got the correct answer by assuming it would move in an ellipse like this :

[image]

i.e. I had assumed that when **q** was given a velocity **v** , it was at  the end point of the semi minor axis(**v** parallel to the major axis), but i cannot digest it.

Why do we have to assume  that **q** starts at the end point of minor axis of ellipse?

Comment: What is the force acting? Just electrostatic I presume.

Comment: Because, in a $1/r^{2}$ potential, the solution for a bound state will be an ellipse (or circle, which is just a special ellipse). The only place where the velocity of an elliptical orbit is parallel to the line joining the foci is on the semi-minor axis. It is just how the math works out.

Comment: @ Jon Custer Why the velocity has to be parallel to the line joining foci?

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of q and Q?

Comment: The motion is physically impossible since charges with the same sign repel. Further, there isn't a single number in this post so the question is impossible to answer even if the signs of charges were different. I recommend the post be move to Arts and Crafts.